# Misplaced alignment tab character &

Tags: tables, errors, longtable, nomenclature

Get that error when i use `\listofnomenclature{ll}` 
it is defined as so in the Thesis.cls file

```
 }
\newcommand\listnomenclature{Symbols}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofnomenclature[2]{
\btypeout{\listnomenclature}
\addtotoc{\listnomenclature}
\chapter*{\listnomenclature
  \@mkboth{
      \MakeUppercase\listnomenclature}    {\MakeUppercase\listnomenclature}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
\cleardoublepage
}
```

use case:

```
\listofnomenclature{ll}

{

\textbf{AC} & \textbf{A}lternating \textbf{C}urrent\\
}
```

A minimal example can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/crwqkoiqr8crldj/AACGzMkXZEOViP0pnO1zhTs1a?dl=0

i have used this in a previous project and it worked fine..

Comment: Please do not use external links for MWE. External links can break. Always add a MWE as code into the question.

Comment: The error message raises if you declare less columns for a tabular (either `tabular`, `longtable`, `tabularx` or similar environments) than you are using or if you try to add an ampersand not using `\&` but the alignment token `&`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke but 2 columns were declared and 2 columns were used ,as seen in the code above.. The ampersand here indicates an alignment token, not the actual ampersand symbol.

Comment: The code snippet at the question does not show any valid usage of `\listofnomenclature`. The `\listofnomenclature{ll}` of the first sentence of your question is not complete (second argument missing). I cannot access the dropbox code currently (and won't if I could). So currently I cannot say anything more than I've done in the comments. Otherwise I would have add an answer instead of a comment. However: Here and now it is to hot, to do any more support. I'm well done.

Comment: @Schweinebacke "i'm well done", i hope that was a pun, considering your username :P i edited the post and added a use case. I cant not add all the code in the question (for example the thesis class is in excess of 300 lines). nonetheless, thanks for your comments (y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some weird reason, it works by removing the spaces.

```
\listofnomenclature{ll}
{\textbf{AC} & \textbf{A}lternating \textbf{C}urrent\\}
```

interesting though, the text output is always centered, even when using `\raggedright`..why is it always centered?

Comment: Don't use answers for questions. If you have a question ask a question (with MWE).

Comment: its a followup question derived from the answer..MWE is that of the original post.

Comment: Follup questions have to be ask as questions not as answers! Put a link into the new question if this question or this answer is relevant for the new question. And: There is still no MWE in the original post. There is only a link to something external, that could be or become a MWE.

Comment: if anyone is interested, change the `[c]` (for center) to `[l]` (for left) in the following line in the Thesis.cls

`\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par`